# Combine multiple ggplot2 plots onto a PDF

Tags: r

I want to be able to plot many plots from ggplot2 into a single PDF.  I have made reproducible code below which creates the error message I am receiving.

```
m <- matrix(data=cbind(rnorm(30, 0), rnorm(30, 2), rnorm(30, 5)), nrow=30, ncol=3)
df <- as.data.frame(m)
dfs <- stack(df)
uniqueplot1=ggplot(dfs, aes(x=values)) + geom_density()
uniqueplot2=ggplot(dfs, aes(x=values)) + geom_density()

objects=ls()
plot_search=grep("uniqueplot",objects)
objects=objects[plot_search]

pdf("plots.pdf")
grid.arrange(objects,ncol=2)
dev.off()
```

The error that I receive is:

```
Error in gList(list("uniqueplot1", "uniqueplot2", wrapvp = list(x = 0.5,  :
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
In addition: Warning message:
In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
```

Is there a way to convert the item `objects` into the correct object type so that it can be used with grid.arrange successfully?

EDIT:  This is a simplified example - in real life I will be producing hundreds of plots, and it will not be possible to list all of these individually.

Comment: Would something like: `grid.arrange(uniqueplot1,uniqueplot2,ncol=2)` work?

Comment: A different approach: have you used RMarkdown before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lapply(objects, get)` in order to create a list with you `ggplot` object (since `objects` contains the a vector of two character`"uniqueplot1" "uniqueplot2"` but not the underlying objects) such as in the following example :

```
m   <- matrix(data = cbind(rnorm(30, 0), rnorm(30, 2), rnorm(30, 5)), nrow  =30, ncol = 3)
df  <- as.data.frame(m)
dfs <- stack(df)

uniqueplot1 <- ggplot(dfs, aes(x = values)) + geom_density()
uniqueplot2 <- ggplot(dfs, aes(x = values)) + geom_density()
objects     <- ls()
plot_search <- grep("uniqueplot",objects)
objects     <- objects[plot_search]

pdf("plots.pdf")
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = lapply(objects, get), ncol = 2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: It's important that I retain the feature of searching through ls(), as in the real life example I will have hundreds of plots generated from multiple loops, and it would not be possible to list them all individually.

Comment: Ok so you can do use `do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange, c(lapply(objects,get), list(ncol=2)))`.

I just modified my answer accordingly

Comment: Also, be careful because in your script, your final `objects` does not contain the two objects `uniqueplot1` and `uniqueplot2`but it is just the vector of these two names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the R idiom would be to store your results from your loops in lists instead of directly in the environment, and then select the desired elements from the lists. You could then use the `grobs` parameter of grid.arrange. Something like this, you'd have to adapt to your example.

```
myplots <- lapply(variables, function(v) 
                ggplot(ggplot(dfs, aes_string(x=v)) + geom_density()
names(myplots) <- variables
plotme <- myplots[grep("pickme", variables)]
grid.arrange(grobs=plotme, ncol=2)
```